# Angular 2 inicializar componente materialize tras obtener datos

Tags: jquery, angularjs-2.0, materialize

Tengo un dropdown que quiero inicializar con materialize en **navbar.component.html**

```
<select>
   <option *ngFor="let survey of surveys" value="{{survey.sid}}">
   {{survey.surveyls_title}}</option>
</select>
```

Los datos los obtengo desde **navbar.component.ts**

```
surveys: Survey[] = [];

    private loadAllSurveys(){
        this.surveyService.getAll().subscribe(surveys => { this.surveys = surveys; });
    }

    /* Aquí inicializo un sidenav de materialize */
    ngAfterViewInit(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".button-collapse").sideNav({
                menuWidth: 300, 
                edge: 'right', 
                closeOnClick: true,
                draggable: true 
            });

        });
     }
```

El problema que tengo es que no sé como inicializar, osea donde colocar el:

```
$('select').material_select();
```

para que se ejecute tras pintar los datos obtenidos mediante el subscribe porque sino me sale vacío e inseleccionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa el evento ngOnInit para acceder al DOM una vez este haya cargado.

Como consejo adicional, usar jQuery y Angular no es buena práctica.

Comment: Gracias Alejandro, es verdad que he leído ya varias veces de no usar jquery con Angular, pero entonces, ¿cómo usarías un framework como Materialize o Bootstrap cuyos componentes se inicializan con jQuery? ¿o es mala práctica también su uso directo?

Comment: Pues tendrás que usar frameworks adaptados para Angular. Bootstrap tiene, para material design también hay, solo que tendras que buscar para Angular

Comment: Material Design: https://material.angular.io/

Comment: Bootstrap: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion

Comment: Muchas gracias, esa es la respuesta que buscaba, no sabía que tenía que buscar la versión adaptada para Angular.

Comment: Me alegro que te sirva, salu2

Answer (score 0):

También buscaba lo mismo y logre llegar a la solución mi archivo **ts** quedo así:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
selector :'menu',
templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
styleUrls:   ['./menu.component.css']
})
export class menu implements OnInit {

constructor(private el:ElementRef){}

ngOnInit() {


$(document).ready(function() {
$('select').material_select();
});

}

chance = [
{modo: 'A'},
{modo: 'B'},
{modo: 'B'},
];

}
```